# How to display a dates in a matrix style?

Tags: php, logic

Consider this scenario, An **employee** can request for a **leave** and a leave consist of one or many **leave_lines** such as:

```
id   leave_id  leave_type   date_from     date_to
1       2      Annual       2019-12-17    2020-01-15
2       2      Off Duty     2020-01-16    2020-01-19
3       2      Holiday      2020-01-20    2020-01-29
```

How can i display this output base on that data:

```
Year | Month    [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21][22][23][24][25][26][27][28][29][30][31]// 1 to 31 (Maximum total number of days of a months
2019  Dec       [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][ A][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ]// Base on the data, leave line start from Dec 12, 2019 and Dec is until 31 only
2020  Jan       [A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][O ][O ][O ][O ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][  ][  ]// Base on the data, the annual leave start from dec 12, 2019 to January 15, 2020, and an Off Duty on January 16 to 19, 2020, also with Holiday on Jan 20 until Jan 29, 2020
```

Here, **A stands for Annual**, **O for Off Duty**, and **H for Holiday**. This is what i have done:

```
if($this->leave->employee_leaves){
    foreach ($this->leave->employee_leaves as $key => $value) {
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(10, 0, '', '', $this->getYear($value->date_from), $border = $bottom, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(11, 0, '', '', $this->getMonth($value->date_from), $border = $bottom, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(16, 0, '', '', "", $border = 0, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);

        for ($i=1; $i <= 31 ; $i++) { 
            if($value->leave_type === 'Annual'){
                $start = $this->getDateFrom('Annual');

                PDF::writeHTMLCell(5, 0, '', '', $i < $start ? "" : "A" , $border = $boxThin, $i == 31 ? $ln = 1 : $ln = 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            }

            if($value->leave_type === 'Off Duty'){
                $start = $this->getDateFrom('Off Duty');
                PDF::writeHTMLCell(5, 0, '', '', $i < $start ? "" : "O" , $border = $boxThin, $i == 31 ? $ln = 1 : $ln = 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            }

            if($value->leave_type === 'Holiday'){
                $start = $this->getDateFrom('Holiday');
                PDF::writeHTMLCell(5, 0, '', '', $i < $start ? "" : "H" , $border = $boxThin, $i == 31 ? $ln = 1 : $ln = 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the output is showing like this which is not i want:

```
Year | Month    [1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15][16][17][18][19][20][21][22][23][24][25][26][27][28][29][30][31]
2019  Dec       [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][ A][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ][A ]
2020  Jan       [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ][O ]
2020  Jan       [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ][H ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly arrange the data in array format like $array[year][month][day]

```
$arrangeData = [];
if ($this->leave->employee_leaves) {
    foreach ($this->leave->employee_leaves as $key => $value) {
        $currentDate = $value->date_form;
        for ($currentDate = $value->date_form; $currentDate <= $value->date_to;) {
            $year = date('Y', strtotime($value->date_from));
            $month = date('M', strtotime($value->date_from));
            $day = date('d', strtotime($value->date_from));

            if ($value->leave_type === 'Annual') {
                $arrangeData[$year][$month][$day] = "A";
            }

            if ($value->leave_type === 'Off Duty') {
                $arrangeData[$year][$month][$day] = "O";
            }

            if ($value->leave_type === 'Holiday') {
                $arrangeData[$year][$month][$day] = "H";
            }
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($value->date_from)));
        }
    }
```

Then output code is

```
    foreach ($arrangeData as $year => $monthData) {
        foreach ($monthData as $month => $days) {

            PDF::writeHTMLCell(10, 0, '', '', $year, $border = $bottom, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            PDF::writeHTMLCell(11, 0, '', '', $month, $border = $bottom, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            PDF::writeHTMLCell(16, 0, '', '', "", $border = 0, 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                $code = isset($days[$i]) ? $days[$i] : "";
                PDF::writeHTMLCell(5, 0, '', '', $code, $border = $boxThin, $i == 31 ? $ln = 1 : $ln = 0, 0, true, 'C', true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above code is not tested

follow the concept only

Comment: Is ```for ($currentDate = $value->date_form; $currentDate <= $value->date_to;)``` don't have terminator? Because my page is keeping on loading.

Comment: $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($value->date_from))); correct this  'd' to 'Y-m-d'

Comment: Why when i use die and dump it only populate the beginning thus ```array:2 [▼
  2019 => array:1 [▼
    "Dec" => array:1 [▼
      17 => "A"
    ]
  ]
  2020 => array:1 [▼
    "Jan" => array:2 [▼
      16 => "O"
      20 => "H"
    ]
  ]
]``` and by the way i replace the loop into ```for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day'))``` because i got infinite loop with the previous one.

Comment: I just made some changes on the loop and also on assigning ```$month, $year, $day``` and it works thank you very much!